# kbd reading Google Sheets Periodically

Tags: kdb

I am looking for a way to read google sheets into kdb periodically? I scoured the internet but couldn't find anything material.

If anyone here can point me in some direction that would be super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Can the google sheet data be scraped using a HTTP get? If so then you may be able to use `.Q.hg`, see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qhg-http-get

But once you get the data into kdb (as a string) it might take a little bit more work to manipulate it such that it could be parsed into a tabular format using `0:`, aka https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#load-csv

However, if the sheet is more advanced than a simple tabular/csv format, it will be tricky to make any sense of it. Do you have a (public) URL for an example google sheet?